# iOS (Swift): representing scaled value as UIColor

Tags: ios, swift, gradient, uicolor

Is there a way to generate a `UIColor` table (or an array of `UIColor`s, say) ranging from `red` to `green` such that a variable `var match = 100` would have a corresponding colour `green` whilst a `var match = 0` would have a corresponding colour `red` and variable values in-between would become greener as their value approaches `100`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a helpful `UIColor` extension that lets you get a blend between two colors based on a percentage.

```
extension UIColor {
    // This function calculates a new color by blending the two colors.
    // A percent of 0.0 gives the "self" color
    // A percent of 1.0 gives the "to" color
    // Any other percent gives an appropriate color in between the two
    func blend(to: UIColor, percent: Double) -> UIColor {
        var fR : CGFloat = 0.0
        var fG : CGFloat = 0.0
        var fB : CGFloat = 0.0
        var tR : CGFloat = 0.0
        var tG : CGFloat = 0.0
        var tB : CGFloat = 0.0

        getRed(&fR, green: &fG, blue: &fB, alpha: nil)
        to.getRed(&tR, green: &tG, blue: &tB, alpha: nil)

        let dR = tR - fR
        let dG = tG - fG
        let dB = tB - fB

        let perc = min(1.0, max(0.0, percent))
        let rR = fR + dR * CGFloat(perc)
        let rG = fG + dG * CGFloat(perc)
        let rB = fB + dB * CGFloat(perc)

        return UIColor(red: rR, green: rG, blue: rB, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
let red = UIColor.red.blend(to: .green, percent: 0)
let mix = UIColor.red.blend(to: .green, percent: 0.5)
let green = UIColor.red.blend(to: .green, percent: 1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this helper function. However, both `UIColor.red.blend(to: .green, percent: 0.0)` and `UIColor.red.blend(to: .green, percent: 1.0)` result in a `UIColor.green` or `UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 1 0 1`. Why is this, please?

Comment: That's what happens when I attempt to make a small change to perfectly working code after posting it here. It's fixed now. The `let perc = ...` line was wrong. Replace that one line with the new one.

Comment: Like a charm -- thank you very much for supplying a neat function. Might I suggest `let perc = min(1.0, max(0.0, percent * 0.01))` ...

Comment: Feel free to setup the parameters as you see fit. All of the `UIColor` values work with values in the range 0.0 to 1.0 so I made this one to treat the percent as 0.0 to 1.0 as well. But feel free to change yours to be 0 to 100 if you want.